# Words that translate to valid words in the source language

Tags: terminology, translation

I recently learned that `poison` in English translates to `gift` in German.  Is there a term for such pairings where the translated word is also a valid word (with unrelated meaning) in the source language?  Any other interesting examples?

Comment: A false friend.

Answer (score 2):

Colin Fine noted in a comment

> [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)

There are some lists of false friends for English available from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:False_cognates_and_false_friends

For German, there is a list of false friends to many other languages here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_falscher_Freunde